# Need help identifying LEGO sets from bags and more

Tags: set-identification

If its possible to please help me identify these, I would great appreciate it. I know some are from Star Wars, but I have no idea what the one with the green torso is from (that bag also has a grey spiked helmet in it if that helps).

There is also a LOT more that I got from thrift stores in plastic tubs and if I can get some help with these bags (and if you guys are up for it) I'd love help deciphering *them* as well.

[image: First Bag with the green torso and helmet]

Comment: Welcome to LEGO Answers! I'm sure that someone would be happy to help identify the other bags that you're unsure about. It would be best to ask that as a separate questions since this one has already been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [Reddish Brown Torso Space Police 3 Spiked Armor Pattern / Sand Green Arms / Sand Green Hands](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0590c01&idColor=88#T=C&C=88) you're dealing with set [5979 Max Security transport](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=83607#T=S&O=%7B%7D).

Comment: The yellow torso and the large Technic projectile seem to confirm your answer as well. Nice find.